# Why triangulation algorithms takes quadratic time in worst case?

Tags: algorithms

[image]

The book says triangulation algorithm takes quadratic time in worst case. but why? The book says - take leftmost vertex and try to connect its neighbors. If you succeed - you get triangle and polygon 
[image]

and therefore as the consequence you get quadratic time algo. But why?
I made this procedure and for a polygon of 7 vertices I performed 4 divisions... 
[image]

In general I do not see how quadratic time is possible... cannot come up with an instance.

Comment: Trying to get an idea about the complexity of something by doing by hand the case n=7 has very little chance of being useful.

Answer (score 3):

Your diagrams are of convex polygons.  The algorithm is for a polygon which may be decidedly concave, with hundreds of edges crossing the $uw$ line.

Comment: Millions even. ${}$